# how to use parameter as list in power shell and create another file based on parameter

Tags: powershell

I want to create multiple file base on this json

```
{
    "Customer":  {
                     "OnSubscription":  true,
                     "Name":  "John",
                     "Surname":  "Smith"
                 },
    "Data":  {
                 "Basket":  [
                                "apples",
                                "pears",
                                "oranges",
                                "strawberries"
                            ]
             }
}
```

Here is my script

```
$json = Get-Content .\basket.json | ConvertFrom-Json
[string[]]$param = "Customer"
Write-Host $param
if ($json.PSObject.Properties.Name -eq $param) {
Write-Host "Valid Customer Key"}
else
{
$message = "Invalid Customer Key" 
Write-Host $message
}
$output = ($json.$param.PSObject.Properties.Name | ForEach-Object {
    "$_={0}" -f $json.$param.$_
}) -join  "`n" 

$Path2 = ".\output\env"
$output | Out-File $Path2
```

Now only create file based on Customer. How to create based on data on basket parameter with list? So have 2 file env which is first env is Customer and another env is basket.

Comment: Could you show us what the desired output needs to look like? The `Customer` one seems to be in an INI type format, but the second one needs to store an array of values..

Comment: this is output from env costumer. OnSubscription=True
Name=John
Surname=Smith

Comment: this is output from env data Basket=apples